# Get website source code from WebView

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I'm trying to get HTML source but it's freezing the app.
I don't know what the problem is and I added Internet Permission
I took this code from a site but it's not working with me. It works until I press the button and then it just freezes.

I hope some one can help me with this, here is the code I'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private String HTML = "";
  EditText tv;
  private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getHTML("http://m.Facebook.com/");  
        }
    });
}

public void getHTML(String paramString)
{
  try
  {
    BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(paramString).openConnection().getInputStream());
    ByteArrayBuffer localByteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
    while (true)
    {
      int i = localBufferedInputStream.read();
      if (i == -1)
      {
        HTML = new String(localByteArrayBuffer.toByteArray());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        return;
      }
      i = (byte)i;
      localByteArrayBuffer.append(i); 

    }
  }
  catch (Exception localException)
  {
    while (true)
      this.HTML = "Error!";
  }
}


private Handler handler = new Handler()

{
  public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
 {

   EditText localEditText = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

   MainActivity.this.m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();

    localEditText.setText(MainActivity.this.HTML);

 }

};


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing network work on your main thread (a big no-no in Android - use an AsyncTask), your error is probably happening here:

```
public void getHTML(String paramString) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(paramString).openConnection().getInputStream());
        ByteArrayBuffer localByteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        while (true) {
            int i = localBufferedInputStream.read();
            if (i == -1) {
                HTML = new String(localByteArrayBuffer.toByteArray());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                return;
            }
            i = (byte) i;
            localByteArrayBuffer.append(i);

        }
    } catch (Exception localException) {
        while (true) // <<< this will create an infinite loop when an error occurs
            this.HTML = "Error!";
    }
}
```

Try removing `while (true)` from your catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

What does this have to to with a WebView? You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadExeption`. You have to put your code in an AsyncTask or Thread to prevent this.